# What is Zin when EN=1?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

The opamp functions only when EN=1, otherwise it is off. When EN =0, Zout = 6kohm.  Also, what does the opamp being "off" imply?
If the opamp is off, does it mean that no current flows inside the opamp at the output node?
P.S. this is my first time asking a question here, please guide me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: 1. more details about op amp part number?

Comment: Most op-amps have very high input impedance; 1 MΩ to 1 GΩ. Yours seems to be 1 kΩ so it doesn't appear to be a regular op-amp. Where did you find this question? [Edit] your question rather than supply missing details in the comments.

Comment: I found this question in an internship test for a company last year. This was the only information that was given. They had mentioned earlier though to make assumptions accordingly

Comment: If means some differential amplifier might act as a unity gain analog amplifier with Zin, and low Zout from negative feedback but when disabled the output Bias is removed  for pullup R and output only has a passive load resistance of 6k to gnd. Perhaps PNP common emitter output.